# The code should filter events from the future, but it does not

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, filter

I have project in old django version - 1.5 (I know better is to upated to newer version, but for now this is not an issue).

I have code connecting with pure sql - I want to have only events from the future - display on list.

Here is my code - some reason I got event from the past. 
I tried without MIN(date), but I got an error:

> more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

```
@register.assignment_tag
def get_teasers():
    return Teaser.objects.extra(select={'next_activity': 'SELECT MIN(date) FROM productions_activity WHERE productions_activity.production_id = home_teaser.production_id'}).filter(Q(online__lte=now()), Q(online_end__gte=now()) | Q(online_end__isnull=True)).order_by('next_activity')
```

Comment: are you sure about sql?.. I dont see `home_teaser` in from or join

Comment: @VaoTsun can you check now code?

Comment: it probably does some kind of lateral subquery?.. sorry - I dont understand how `SELECT MIN(date) FROM productions_activity WHERE productions_activity.production_id = home_teaser.production_id'` work as it should not in isolation

Answer (score 0):

Add `.last()` at the end of the sentence

Comment: I got an error: `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'last'`

Comment: You are right, it doesn't exist in django 1.5 Try an order by at the end of the statement using something like this `.order_by('next_activity')[-1]`